# \cos etc. do not use correct font (beamer class)

Tags: beamer, fonts, eulervm

I'm trying to use Palatino and EulerVM in a latex presentation (using beamer).
However, in my \align environment `\cos` is not displayed correctly. It uses a different font and is thus much too large.

Here is a MWE so you can see what I mean

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% General Setup


\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[T1,small,euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage{bm}



%% Beamer Layout %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\useoutertheme[subsection=false,shadow]{miniframes}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamerfont{title like}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape}

\setbeamercolor*{lower separation line head}{bg=DeepSkyBlue4} 
\setbeamercolor*{upper separation line foot}{bg=DeepSkyBlue4}

\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{fg=Firebrick4} 
\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=black} 
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=black} 

\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=DeepSkyBlue4}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=DeepSkyBlue4!10!white}


\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 












%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin Document



\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Apply L\"owdin partitioning to ET - Results}
    \begin{block}{Test}
        \begin{align*}
            E[\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3]=& E_0[\sigma_1,\sigma_2] \notag\\
                &+\cos(\phi)E_{\cos(\phi)}\notag\\
                &+\cos^2(\phi)E_{\cos^2(\phi)}\notag\\
                &+\sin(\phi)E_{\sin(\phi)}+\mathcal{O}(V^4)
        \end{align*}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `serif` option within the class:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress,serif]{beamer}
```

Also, to align, use `&=`.

Comment: But what about linebreaks. The second line would then not be correctly aligned.

Comment: And `\cos` and `\sin` are still larger than `cos` or `sin`.

Comment: @MrZ, no. `cos $\cos$` produce the same effect.

Comment: You can use `&{\quad}+` to move the plus sign to the right.

Comment: Ok. It seems that the `small` was the problem.

Comment: `$cos$` is not the right way to type math functions. To LaTeX, it is simply 3 constants.

Comment: Compare `$cos x$` with `$\cos x$`.

Comment: I know, but it seems that `$cos x$` still uses a slightly smaller font than `$\cos x$`. Thus `$\cos x$` does not integrate well into expressions. But it seems, I would need some option to scale down the serif font.

Comment: `\cos` makes use of the same fonts as in the text since you are writing a name of a function, so it is 'text'.

Comment: @MrZ Do not ask whether the font is larger or smaller -- better ask whether the result is pleasant. I consider the result of default beamer font mixed with eulervm quite good as they are, with no further modifications :)